# SoapUI header - difference between header in soapenv:Header element in xml, and gui header option at bottom of SoapUI

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

[image]

As you can see in that image, you can add headers to the XML element *soapenv:Header*, OR you can add it at the bottom with the green plus button.

But when you add a header using the green plus button, it is not added to the XML message.

So, what is the difference between both types of headers?

Thanks

Comment: The top part represents the message payload - so the payload has a node called "Header". The bottom part represents the http attributes. (Lots) More info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol and here https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/teststep-reference/http-request/headers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly explained in the comment of your question.

Here i have tried to give an example to explain the visual difference

[image]

Check out the **circle things** are the headers you added via the **Green button** i.e. they are the headers which will be not part of your XML

But they are the headers for the overall request. So its like metadata which would be helpful in knowing where to direct your request

```
header2: oktest
soapaction: www.test.com
```

But the header highlighted with Arrow is part of your payload i.e. XML which would be used by the application for processing the request.

```
</testns:header>
```

This you can see in the **Raw** tab of your **request** XML